# Can't import modules in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time trying to import modules created inside a project.

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
myapp/calcs/__init__.py
myapp/calcs/calculations.py
myapp/tests/__init__.py
myapp/tests/test_calcs.py
```

Inside test_calcs.py, I have the following import statement:

```
from calcs import calculations as clc
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named calcs
```

I can't understand why I am having this error as I have included an **init**.py file inside calcs which should make it act as a module.

Comment: And the folder `myapp` is in the Python path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) describe how you can solve this pretty well!

Short version:

- change `from calcs import calculations as clc` to `from ..calcs import calculations as clc`
- start a terminal session in the parent folder of **myapp**
- run `python -m myapp.tests.test_calcs.py`

Answer (score 1):

I also found this part of python extremely confusing. You basically need to make your project an installable package and do an editable install of it in your environment to import your modules this way. I would recommend [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhUpxWjOhME) for a great walkthrough on the process, you only need to watch 2:36-8:36 for this topic specifically but the whole video is quite useful. Best of luck.